# Keep trailing zeros when manipulating vector between character and number

Tags: r, character

I feel like this should be obvious but I am not seeing it. I have a dataframe I need to reorder with column names that are number stored as characters.  For example, names(df) produces  c("1.5", "1.51", "1.0"). My approach was going to be extract names, convert to number, sort, convert to character, pass to R indexing.

> x<-c("1.5", "1.51", "1.0")
>
> y<-as.numeric(x)

1.50 1.51 1.00  #it is padding it with an extra 0 but I think I can live with that.

> z<-sort(y)

1.00 1.50 1.51 #no surprises there...

> as.character(z)

"1" "1.5" "1.51"

I would like to maintain the trailing 0s, either relative to original input vector or the padded output vector from as.numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have the following df:

```
df <- data.frame("a", "b", "c")
names(df)<- c("1.5", "1.51", "1.0")

> df
  1.5 1.51 1.0
1   a    b   c
```

We can simply get the order of the columns and call them in that order like this

```
df[,order(as.double(names(df)))]

 1.0 1.5 1.51
1   c   a    b
```

This allows you to keep the original formatting of your column names